# OpenCV find polygons

Tags: opencv, polygon, detection, emgucv

I'm using EmguCV and trying to find polygons within an image.  Here are some facts about the problem:

1) The polygons are irregularly shaped, but the sides are always at one of two angles.

2) Often the polygons have gaps in their sides that need to be filled.

3) If a polygon is contained within another polygon, I want to ignore it.

Consider this image:

[image]

And I want to find the polygons highlighted in red, omit the polygon highlighted in green and make connections across gaps as shown in blue here:

[image]

I've had some success using HoughLinesBinary and then connecting the closest line segment end points to each other to bridge gaps to build a complete polygon, but this doesn't work when multiple polygons are involved since it will try to draw lines between polygons if they happen to be close to each other.

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Why exactly should the lowest blue line be added that way and not 2 blue lines in an right angle? All in all you might want to use results of "gestalt psychology" (google it).

Comment: It would actually be more accurate if the lowest blue line was turned into two lines at a right angle.  I didn't think that would be feasible since that area of the image is obscured, but if it is possible, that's great.

Comment: It should all be about grouping existing elements/lines to objects (distance/continuity etc are factors to decide to which object qn element belongs). And how to fill the gaps in an object. Both topics are covered by gestalt psychology research, but might still be open problems :)

Comment: I'm pretty new to coding for image processing and still struggle with the meaning of the arguments to the HoughLines methods... I'm definitely not advanced enough to start applying experimental psychological principles to my code.

Comment: So you want your code to fill gaps like a human being would do it but you want to achieve that by simple methods? Try simple heuristics (distance) to cluster edge segments to objects, but dont expect this to work for every input!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem could be your image threshold.
I don't know how you did but you can get better results if the binary image is better.

I like of your idea to connect the polygons segment, try to secure that the line you will connect has a maximum and minimum length to avoid connect to nearest objects.

Verify if the new joint of lines forms 90 degrees angle, even if its a corner.

Added:
You can use moephological operators to grow the lines acord to angles. As you said that the lines has known angles do dilations using a mask like this

0 0 0
1 1 0
0 0 0

This mask will grow lines only to rigth until conect to other side.

Comment: The binary image is actually really good, relative to the input image.  The gaps in the sides of the polygon really exist in the input image because those areas are obscured by other images.

Answer (score 0):

A general solution will be hard, but for your particular problem a relatively simple heuristic should work.

The main idea is to use the white pixels on one side of a wall as an additional feature. The walls in your image always have one almost black side, and one side with many white noise pixels. The orientation of the white noise in relation to the wall does not switch on corners, so using this information you can eliminate a lot of possible connections between lines.

**First some definitions:**

All walls in the picture go either from the lower left to the upper right (a rising line) or from the upper left to the lower right (a falling line).

If there are more white pixels on the left side of a falling line, call it *falling-left-wall*, otherwise *falling-right-wall*. Same for rising lines.

Each line ends in two points. Call the leftmost one *start*, the rightmost one *end*.

**Now for the algorithm:**

- classify each line and each start/endpoint in the image.
  Check the immediate area on both sides of each line, and see which side contains more white pixels.
  Afterwards, you have a list of points labeled *falling-left-wall-start*, rising-left-wall-end, etc.
- for each start/end point:

  - look for nearby start/end points from another line
  - if it is a *falling-left-wall-start*, only look for:

    - a falling-left-wall-end
    - a rising-left-wall-start, if that point is on the left side of the current line
    - a rising-right-wall-end, if that point is on the right side of the current line
  - pick the closest point among the found points, connect it to the current point.